# Map attributes on click

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a feature collection consisting of hundreds of farmer polygons. The shapefile contains the farmers' data such as name, region, crop, and area of ​​the polygon. I have adapted a code that allows me to export the average ndvi values ​​of each polygon to CSV format. I would like to add to the code, some functionality, in the earth engine map, to visualize the attributes of each polygon when clicking on it (name, region, crop, medium NDVI).Also, since I have hundreds of farmers, is there the possibility of enabling a search engine on the map? That is, enter, for example, the name or the identifier of the farmer to go directly to his polygon. This is possible? Could someone help me on that? I share the current code that I have.

```
var destoque = ee.FeatureCollection("users/marcelos/destoque")
Map.centerObject(destoque)
Map.addLayer(destoque)

var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterDate('2021-05-01', '2021-06-01')
  .filterBounds(destoque)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20)
  
  var maskcloud = function(image) {
  var QA60 = image.select(['QA60']);
  return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1))
}

var NDVI = function(image) {
  return image.expression(
    '(NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)', {
      'NIR': image.select('B8'),
      'RED': image.select('B4'),
    }).rename('NDVI').copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
}

var NDVIcol = S2.map(maskcloud)
  .map(NDVI)
  
var ts = NDVIcol.map(calculateFarmersNDVI)

function calculateFarmersNDVI(image) {
  var properties = ee.Dictionary(
    destoque.iterate(function(region, acc) {
      return ee.Dictionary(acc)
        .combine(
          ndviForArea(image, ee.Feature(region))
        )
    }, ee.Dictionary())
  )
  return ee.Feature(null, properties
    .set('Year', image.date().get('year'))
    .set('Month', image.date().get('month'))
    .set('Day', image.date().get('day'))
  )
}

function ndviForArea(image, region) {
  var ndvi = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: region.geometry(),
    scale: 30
  }).get('NDVI')
  // Not all characters are valid property names in EE
  // dictionaries. Replace them with _
  var farmers = region.getString('name')
    .replace('\\W', '_', 'g')
    
    // There might be images without any value for the region.
  // ee.Dictionary.set() must have a non-null value.
  // The If() statement replaces null with an empty string.
  var ndviOrBlank = ee.Algorithms.If(ndvi, ndvi, '')
  return ee.Dictionary().set(farmers, ndviOrBlank)
}

var listOfFarmers = ee.List(destoque.aggregate_array('name'))
  .map(function (farmers) { 
    return ee.String(farmers).replace('\\W', '_', 'g')
  })
ee.List(['Year', 'Month', 'Day'])
  .cat(listOfFarmers)  
  // We want to provide toDrive() selectors, to
  // get the CSV columns ordered. This must be a 
  // client-side object though, so we need to call
  // evaluate() on it before using it.
  .evaluate(function (selectors) {
    Export.table.toDrive({
      collection: ts,
      description: 'test_destoque_ndvi',
      fileFormat: 'CSV',
      selectors: selectors
    })    
  })
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/84f5a4b11daedae6f83a11a2da15b647

Comment: your asset is not publically available so we can't help you with this example! Did you check out some example questions that are already here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329080/google-earth-engine-get-image-value-on-click or this example: https://ecodata.nrel.colostate.edu/gdpe-gee-remote-sensing-lessons/module10.html

Comment: Thanks, I think the asset is now accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understanding all the things you want but this is my try.. You can access features interactively with

> Map.onClick()

With a spatial filter you can then filter your featureCollection to the nearest feauture. You can then filter your image collection or original feature Collection to add these details to the map or console. I'm guessing you want a time series of NDVI for the selected feature?

Alternatively you can also create a list of your farmers name like this:

```
var farmerList = 
ee.List(destoque.distinct('name').reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), 
      ["name"]).get('list')).flatten()
var listOfFarmers = farmerList
  .map(function (farmers) { 
    return ee.String(farmers).replace('\\W', '_', 'g')
  })
```

You can use that list create a dropdown panel with a select:

```
var dropdownPanel = ui.Panel({
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'),
  style: {height: '50px', width:'350px'}
});
var countrySelector = ui.Select({
  placeholder: 'please wait..',
  onChange: loadData
  });

// replace the position selector with the position labels available.
posString.evaluate(function(farmerList) {
  countrySelector.items().reset(farmerList);
  countrySelector.setPlaceholder('select a farmer');
});

dropdownPanel.add(countrySelector)
// dropdownPanel.add(posSelector);
Map.add(dropdownPanel)
```

see the link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/94827bcc770e269c772bae7489b93e2c

**EDIT 9/7/2021**
new link after suggestions: https://code.earthengine.google.com/297ece52ef1990b27acdd83cdecf32db

be aware you have to finetune yourself with your own custom functions. You have to option to click in the map on a polygon and do something or select farmer from a dropdown list. Also the gui is not very stable as you have to restart the script if you want to select another farmer.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly, maybe the translation is not the best. Basically, the code that I have adapted calculates the average NDVI of each farmer contained in my featurecollection, and exports it in CSV format. I need two more things:
1: When clicking on any polygon on the map, a panel is displayed, showing the attributes of the corresponding asset (farmer's name) and the NDVI. 2: In case you want to search specifically for a farmer on the map, enable a function of selecting the farmer's name, and after, automatically zoom to the corresponding polygon with the asset information.

Comment: It is just that your function 'calculateFarmersNDVI' is unclear in what you want with it. The resulting imageCollection 'ts' doesn't make much sense. I already made the dropdown menu in the example available so in the function loaddata you can do anything you want, I made an example. In the previous example there was already the possibility to click in the map on a feature and show the time series of NDVI. You can add yourself a printing statement or put it in an information panel.. I'll update the answer with a new link.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries. If you feel this answered you question it might be nice to accept it as suggested answer to your questions.